# In Cakephp 3.x, What is the Best Practice for Removing [Username] from a Plugin you install with composer?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

When you install a plugin with composer, by default it puts it into ROOT/vendor/[username]/[plugin-name].  This also updates ROOT/vendor/cakephp-plugins.php with something like

```
return [
    'plugins' => [
        '[UserName]/[PluginName]' => $baseDir . '/vendor/[username]/[plugin-name]/'
    ]
];
```

This apparently also makes it so that your plugin's namespace should be something like.

```
namespace [Username]\[PluginName]\Controller;
```

And when you do a redirect (as an example) you refer to it with something like...

```
$this->redirect(['plugin' => '[Username]/[PluginName]', 'controller' => '[Controller]', 'action' => 'index']);
```

What is the best practice for removing [Username] from when you reference a plugin that you install with composer?

Comment: The best practice would be to not fiddle with that. Why would want to do that anyways?

Comment: If you're ending up with URLs that you don't like, then the solution is to use routing to map a URL that you do like to the plugin.

Comment: @GregSchmidt It has nothing to do with urls.  @ndm You might want to do it if you don't care to use your username every single place you want to call your plugin from.  eg. `use UserName\PluginName\Model\Table;`, when instead it can be the shorter `use PluginName\Model\Table;`.

Comment: Just be aware that if you do this, you open yourself up to namespace conflicts. With autocompletion in most modern IDEs, there's really no more typing required to include the user name in your `use` statement than not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is simply to remove your username from the autoload parameter in your plugin's composer.json file.

It looked like this::

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Username\\PluginName\\": "src"
    }
},
```

It should look like this

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "PluginName\\": "src"
    }
},
```

Comment: You presumably also need to manually move all the folders that get created when you use composer to install new plugins, and I don't know what that would do to the update process.

Comment: Nope, not needed.  The file vendor/cakephp-plugins.php takes care of that, and is automatically created/updated when you install with composer.