# How to 'Uninstall' or 'Remove' plugin using composer?

Tags: cakephp, plugins, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I have installed some unnecessary plugins in my cakephp3 project, I want to remove/uninstall from my project, I'm not able to find any solutions. Will any suggest me what I do?

`How to 'Uninstall' plugin using composer, which installed by the composer in cakephp3?`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35611502/in-cakephp-3-x-what-is-the-best-practice-for-removing-username-from-a-plugin

Comment: Why not use `composer remove` as in all other cases?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
composer remove packageauthor/packagename --update-with-dependencies
```

You can also modify your composer.json to get rid of what you don't want and run `composer update`

Comment: If i want to remove `cakephp-mailgun` plugin,
 i have to remove from `composer.json`,

 Before change,
 `"require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.16",
        "cakephp/cakephp": "3.1.13",
        "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "2.*",
        "cakephp/migrations": "~1.0",
        "cakephp/plugin-installer": "*",
        "motsmanish/cakephp-mailgun": "^1.0"  //I want to remove this one
    }`
    after this changes, I have to just Run `composer update`, right?

Comment: OR
composer remove motsmanish/cakephp-mailgun --update-with-dependencies

this one?

Comment: or just run composer remove motsmanish/cakephp-mailgun --update-with-dependencies, should work

Comment: Let me try..., Thank you!

Comment: to add. you can remove global plugins with `composer global remove packageauthor/packagename`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `composer remove packageauthor/packagename` because the `--no-update-with-dependencies` has been deprecated and it's by default right now.